# FabricJS adding Image to Group causes odd control behavior

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I'm attempting to add a loaded image into a fabric Group object.  Everything looks ok, but the selection controls aren't selectable and I can't drag the object around. The top left control works though and after clicking it everything is fine.

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a9fahrxd/1/) that demonstrates the behavior.

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', { 
  width: 200, 
  height: 200
});
var group = new fabric.Group();
canvas.add(group);
fabric.Image.fromURL('https://placehold.it/100x100', function(img) {
  group.addWithUpdate(img);
  canvas.setActiveObject(group);
  canvas.renderAll();
});
```

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I currently have a workaround where I'm just reinitializing the group as a completely new instance and passing the image in to the constructor.  Seems to work that way, but adding to an existing group is still not working.

Comment: just call group.setCoords(); after doing addWithUpdate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some performance reason, fabricjs does not call setCoords automatically after adding objects to a group ( in case of many object added you can call setCoords just once ).

So after doing addWithUpdate, just call group.setCoords();

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', { 
  width: 200, 
  height: 200
});
var group = new fabric.Group();
canvas.add(group);
fabric.Image.fromURL('https://placehold.it/100x100', function(img) {
  group.addWithUpdate(img);
  group.setCoords();
  canvas.setActiveObject(group);
  canvas.renderAll();
});
```

Comment: That works!  I would have never figured that out.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I came across this post because I was having trouble getting the positioning of images to work properly. I ended up finding that it's easier to just create create an image element using `document.createElement` and set the `src`, then feed that into `fabric.Image` with all the options you need (instead of using `fabric.Image.fromURL` which was too much of a headache to use), before adding it to the group.

```
var oImg = document.createElement("img");
oImg.setAttribute('src', 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/92/Cog_font_awesome.svg/512px-Cog_font_awesome.svg.png');
var i = new fabric.Image(oImg, {
    originX: 'center',
    originY: 'center',
    left: left+35,
    top: top-30,
    scaleX:.05,
    scaleY:.05,
});
g = new fabric.Group([r, t, i]); // where r and t are other fabric objects
```